# java IOException not being thrown from socket Connection

Tags: java, sockets, ioexception, internal-server-error

I am making an a call to a proxy server and providing the wrong credentials on purpose.  However the IOE exception is not being thrown.  Instead an internal error with the message that "you should not be here".

Any idea why an IOE is not begin thrown just like the java docs?  I created a brand new project just to be sure my other program wasn't causing any issues.

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
    import java.net.Proxy;
    import java.net.Socket;


     public class socketTesting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new            InetSocketAddress("<proxyServer>", 8080));

       Socket sock = new Socket(proxy);
       try
       {
       sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress("<endpoint server>",443));
       }
       catch (IOException e)
       {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
   }

  }
```

If the proxy creds are correct, the connection works without any issues.

Comment: Please show all of your code, including imports, as well as the output that you are actually receiving.

Comment: That is all my code.  I simplified it.   For some reason when you have wrong proxy creds it throws an internal error and not an IOEException.  Should be easy to repro.

Comment: "That is all my code." No, it isn't. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I updated my sample code in a new project just to be sure nothing in my previous project was causing an issue.

Comment: @rmlan there you go full code.

Comment: Yeah, I was actually able to reproduce. It looks like any error that is thrown by HttpUrlConnection gets swallowed up as a "ReflectiveOperationException" and re-thrown, which then results in the throwing of the InternalError. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: The interesting part is that I get the same internal error if i just try to connect to the proxy and leave the end point out of the mix.

Comment: Right, but the Cause chain should end up at a different Exception, or at least a different message.

Comment: It isn't documented, or at last not well, but you can't use am HTTP Proxy with a `Socket`, only with an `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: Interesting, but when I use a socket with an http proxy it works when the right creds are supplied.